# Can we have a SQL query that lists all the tables that are not referred in any procedures within a database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, procedure

SQL query which will list all the tables of a database that are not being used in any procedures.

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server? Answers can be very different depending on version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much cleaner than parsing procedure bodies IMHO:

```
SELECT s.name, t.name
  FROM sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
      INNER JOIN sys.procedures AS p
      ON d.referencing_id = p.[object_id]
      WHERE d.referenced_id = t.[object_id]
  );
```

Note this will not capture stored procedures that take table names as parameters or build them dynamically and execute as dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  name into #temp from sys.tables

update #temp 
set name = CONCAT('%',name,'%')

select name into #temp2 from #temp
delete from #temp2


insert into #temp2
SELECT T.Name FROM sys.procedures SP, #temp T
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE T.name

SELECT * FROM #temp
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM #temp2

drop table #temp
drop table #temp2
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Doesn't work for me (Aaron's answer does) as I'm on SQL 2008R2 and am at the mercy of capita as to when I can upgrade my sql server!

Comment: @JonTout: the only thing in here that won't work in 2008R2 is `CONCAT`, which is trivially replaced (`set name = '%' + name + '%'`). That still doesn't make this a very good approach, though.